# Bootstrap column doesnt work with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to style some radio buttons to make them look like regular buttons.  They do work, look and act as regular buttons but when I try to place those buttons in 3 different columns (`col-sm-4, col-sm-4, col-sm-4`) it doesn't "recognize" or not sure what is it...I try to place the columns as a class inside a `label` but it didn't work.  Like this:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" >

                <label class="col-sm-4 btn btn-project-type">

                        <input type="radio" name="project_type"  class="form-control" >Web Site

                </label>

                <label class="col-sm-4 btn btn-project-type">

                        <input type="radio" name="project_type" class="form-control" >Application

                </label>

                <label class="col-sm-4 btn btn-project-type">

                        <input type="radio" name="project_type" class="form-  control" >Something Else

                </label>

 </div>
```

So, then I tried to create 3 columns inside the `<div data-toggle="buttons">`  But it is not hitting the label..

all I want is to place those 3 radio buttons in 3 different columns and make them work like radio buttons:

|            |            |           |
|  Button 1  |  Button 2  |  Button 3 |
|            |            |           |

Here is my CSS:

```
.btn-project-type{
border-color: $green;
color:$white;
width: 100%;
background-color: $dark-grey;
border: 1px solid $green;
  }

 .btn-project-type:hover {
  border-color: $green;
  color: $white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $blue;
  border: 1px solid $green;

  }

 .btn.active, .btn:active {
  background-color: $blue;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Labels aren't typically used as wrapper like that. They are meant to add text labels to inputs. I'm guessing the labels are set to `display: inline;` which might affect the bootstrap col layout.

I adjusted your html syntax slightly and added divs as wrapper instead. I also romoved `.form-control` class on the inputs which might have also been messing with things. https://jsfiddle.net/gwfxd42t/

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" >
  <div class="col-sm-4 btn btn-project-type">
    <label>Something Else</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_type"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 btn btn-project-type">
    <label>Something Else</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_type"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 btn btn-project-type">
    <label>Something Else</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_type"/>
  </div>           
 </div>
```